# Set cells to be 1/n width of whole table

Tags: tables

I'm drawing a table where the center element is much larger (multicolumn) than the other elements, and its causing the last element of the table to stretch, however I want to stretch them all equally.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Infrared Sensor drivers}\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make them stretch equally, or do I have to make each one a `p{\widthof{Inrared Sensor Drivers}/3}`? I have lots of tables to do this to which is why I'm looking for a nicer solution

Comment: is `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{>\centering\arraybackslas}X|}}` an option? in preamble you should load package `tabularx`.

Comment: @Zarko After fixing the bracketing (`\begin{tabularx}{*{3}{>\centering\arraybackslash}X|}`), this gives me a "Missing number treated as zero" error.

Comment: Brydon, You need to add @Zarko to your comment if you want him to be alerted.

Comment: @BrydonGibson, see edited comment i forget on width of `tabularx` :-(

Comment: @BrydonGibson: You forgot the `{\linewidth}`, and your table will still be to wide, since there is inter column spacing

Comment: Can someone explain the `>` syntax? What does it do?

Comment: @BrydonGibson: Are you after something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Fg1.png)?

Comment: @Werner That's exactly what I'm after, the solution I've accepted gives that.

Comment: @BrydonGibson: The solution gives something different from the looks of it.

Comment: @Werner I'm wrapping it in the correct width, it's all put into a newcommand and that's being used in a tikz box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing is to define a new columntype (with `array` package and `\newcolumntype`, say `Y` and apply centering in there.

`tabularx` will use the value of the first argument ( `{\linewidth}` here) and spread the remaining space equally among all `X` columns (or such types that derive from X, so `Y` as well.

But even this will produce overfull boxes, since there is inter-column space, the `\tabcolsep` at the left and right margin of the table. This can be disabled with `@{}`.

The `showframe` package shows the nice fitting into the line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{3}{Y}@{}}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Infrared Sensor drivers}\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

let mi convert my comment to the answer:¸

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mccc[1]{\multicolumn{3}%
                                {>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
                                {#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{C | C | C}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    \hline
    \mccc{Infrared Sensor drivers}\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

in use of `multicolumn` i assume the content of this cell can be longer than table width.

[image]